# Make search term disappear after search in SearchView

Tags: android, search, searchview

I have a main activity that I can initiate a search and go to searchable activity. I use SearchcView to conduct the search. I also have onDestroy in the main activity.

After a search, when I hit Back button to go back to the main activity, I can still see my search term in the action bar. Apparently the onDestroy doesn't remove that. How can I make the search term go away?

**Main Activity**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.all_stores, menu);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

    super.onDestroy();
    db.close();
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't know the syntax but you want to set the search term to null after you click search. I have done this before in an `onClick` method but I'm not too familiar with `SearchManager`

Answer (score 3):

In **onCreateOptionsMenu** add,

```
searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
if(searchItem.isActionViewExpanded())
    searchItem.collapseActionView();
else
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In your **Activity** add,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {       
    if(searchItem.isActionViewExpanded())
        searchItem.collapseActionView();
    else
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

If you want to target lower versions,

```
MenuItemCompat.collapseActionView(searchItem);
MenuItemCompat.isActionViewExpanded(searchItem);
```